# NAO V5 - wrong encoder(s) data

Tags: nao-robot

So I have bought a nao v5 and it has a small problem which came with it.
I’ll describe here the issue, what I’ve tried and my main question to try and classify the cause of the problem.

Ao the current and only issue with the robot is that his encoders seem to send wrong positioning data.

As shown in the following image:
[image]

On the app, I’ve tested and moved the arms manually and it does show a movement. But still while his arms and head are straight forward the encoders send something else and massed up (as can be seen in the image)

So my questions are

1. Is that issue happened to anyone? Is there a way to calibrate the encoders? (By factory reset or uploading a new OS?)
2. Are the encoders inside the motors? Because since the motors aren’t moving I want to check if the motors even work (if not, what are the ways I can check if the motors has burned out or his controller? Does the robot alert when a motor/motor controller burn?)

If you can help me any further with this I would like to hear more, I want to fix this by my own other than sending it for repair at the company. (It’s not under warranty anymore)

Comment: If the problem persists after hard reboot and if it moves in the correct direction when you move arms, then a recalibration could correct the problem. However I'm not sure the calibration process is publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

This is a calibration issue that happens from time to time.
Only the support teams has the tools to recalibrate the robot.
You need to contact them.